# How can convert the JQuery code to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert the following JQuery code to JavaScript...

My html code :

```
<input type="text" id="state" data-toggle="dropdown" placeholder="State">
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-state" aria-labelledby="state" role="menu">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">value1</a>
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">value2</a>
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">value3</a>
</div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$('.dropdown-menu-state .dropdown-item').on('click', function(){
   $("#state").val($(this).text());
});
```

Javascript Code:

```
document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu-state .dropdown-item").addEventListener("click", function() {
   document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = this.text();
});
```

Actually, I want to enter a dropdown-item value to text input after clicking.
But it doesn't work.

Comment: "But I can't" - why? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: There is no error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points:

- `$(selector)` is closer to `document.querySelectorAll(selector)` than to `document.querySelector(selector)`. So you'll want the former, and to iterate over the returned *NodeList*.
- jQuery `.val( value )` will set the `.value` property when called on an object that points to an HTMLElement that has such property (like your `<input>`). So that what you want to set, not the `.innerHTML` which wouldn't have any positive effects on this element.
- `.text()` is also a jQuery method. As a getter it's equivalent to `Node.textContent`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu-state .dropdown-item")
  .forEach( function( elem ) {
    elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
     document.getElementById("state").value = this.textContent;
    });
  });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="state" data-toggle="dropdown" placeholder="State">
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-state" aria-labelledby="state" role="menu">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">value1</a>
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">value2</a>
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">value3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Each time I click on the input the dropdown will open and then the value will be input by clicking on the dropdown.

Comment: @behi1989 this code does exactly the same as [the jQuery version](https://jsfiddle.net/kcj49ar7/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly detect click event on select options. Instead you can do this on select change event like this.

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu-state")[0];
dropdown.addEventListener('change', function() {
   document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="state"></div>
<select class="dropdown-menu-state">
  <option value="1" class="dropdown-item">text1</option>
  <option value="2" class="dropdown-item">text2</option>
  <option value="3" class="dropdown-item">text3</option>
  <option value="4" class="dropdown-item">text4</option>
  <option value="5" class="dropdown-item">text5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this site could prove useful to you [You might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

So you can 'divide and conquer'.